# html can not read cods on script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, script-tag

how can i edit script code in html to see result

- whole parts of html code work so well but whatever in script tag dosen't work
- i wanna add scroll animation to my html
- did i wrong to use scripts src ?
- did i use javascript code in wrong way ?

**here is whole my html scripts tag:**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TimelineMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>
<script>
var tl = new TimelineMax({onUpdate:updatePercentage});
var tl2 = new TimelineMax();
const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

tl.from('blockquote', .5, {x:200, opacity: 0});
tl.from('span', 1, { width: 0}, "=-.5");
tl.from('#office', 1, {x:-200, opacity: 0,ease: Power4.easeInOut}, "=-1");
tl.from('#building', 1, {x:200, opacity: 0, ease: Power4.easeInOut}, "=-.7");

tl2.from("#box", 1, {opacity: 0, scale: 0});
tl2.to("#box", .5, {left: "20%", scale: 1.3, borderColor: 'white', borderWidth: 12, boxShadow: '1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.09)'})

const scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: ".sticky",
            triggerHook: "onLeave",
            duration: "100%"
})
  .setPin(".sticky")
  .setTween(tl)
        .addTo(controller);

const scene2 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: "blockquote"
})
  .setTween(tl2)
        .addTo(controller);


function updatePercentage() {
  //percent.innerHTML = (tl.progress() *100 ).toFixed();
  tl.progress();
  console.log(tl.progress());
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can't add code inside a script with the `src` attribute set, try moving the code to a separate script tag.

Comment: Are multiple `src`s in a script tag supposed to be working?

Comment: no i edited that it was a mistake